# Kafka Connect JDBC Connector Sink - Update table values using a field that is in the key used as the pk.fields

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We would like to configure a connector using the below schema:

Key

```
id: String
status: String
```

Value:

```
status: String
```

We would like to use the key to identify the rows in the database to update, and use the value field's to update the given fields in the db. However, it seems that the connector wants to only allow one usage of the status field. Is this achievable?

Ideally, we would like the update statements to look something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable 
set status = value.status
where status = key.status and id = key.id
```

We have tried the below configuration, but it is not giving the expected result:

```
pk.mode=record_key
pk.fields=status,id
```

This currently results in the below query (note that it is missing the key.status in the set fields):

```
UPDATE "public"."myTable" SET  
WHERE "id" = 'idgoeshere' AND "status" = 'ENABLED'
```

Any input on this would be appreciated!

Comment: so you've got two fields called `status` that are different things, is that right?

Comment: What you describe I think *should* work. I wrote about it [here](https://rmoff.net/2021/03/12/kafka-connect-jdbc-sink-deep-dive-working-with-primary-keys/#_using_the_key_of_the_kafka_message_as_the_primary_key_option_2_structured_keys).

Comment: @RobinMoffatt they have different values, as I would like to use the 'key' status to identify the row to update. The 'value' is a different value, as I would like to update the row's status to that value.